# Time difference of two simultaneous events happening in an inertial frame of reference w.r.t another inertial frame of reference that is moving?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Two simultaneous events are happening in a stationary inertial frame of reference ($S$), but they are happening at different positions. First event is happening at $x=x_1$; $t=t_1$, second event is happening at $x=x_2$; $t=t_2$.

$$t_1=t_2$$

$$x_1\ne x_2$$

The question is what is the time difference of these two events with respect to another inertial frame of reference ($S'$) that is moving along $x'$-axis with speed $V$?

My solution:

These events are happening simultaneously with respect to $$S frame of reference and we know the times of events happening. We need to find the timings of the events in $S'$ frame of reference. Using Lorentz transformations,

$$t^{'}=\gamma(t-\frac{V}{c^2}x)$$

$$\Delta{t^{'}}=\gamma(\Delta{t}-\frac{V}{c^2}\Delta{x})$$

$$\Delta{x}=x_2-x_1\ne 0, \Delta{t}=t_2-t_1=0$$

$$\Delta{t^{'}}=\gamma(-\frac{V}{c^2}\Delta{x})=-\gamma\frac{V}{c^2}\Delta{x}\ne 0$$

I found the solution this way but when I check the solution in the book which I found the question, it shows like that:

$$t_1^{'}=\gamma(x_1-\frac{V}{c^2}t_1), t_2{'}=\gamma(x_2-\frac{V}{c^2}t_2)$$

$$t_2^{'}-t_1^{'}=\gamma(x_2-x_1-\frac{V}{c^2}[t_2-t_1])=\gamma(x_2-x_1)=\gamma\Delta{x}$$

I don't understand the solution shown in my book. I haven't ever seen that equation $t^{'}=\gamma(x-\frac{V}{c^2}t)$, all I have seen about time dilation is $t^{'}=\gamma(t-\frac{V}{c^2}x)$.

Which is the correct solution? If you can explain, I would be very happy.

Comment: The equation from your book isn't dimensionally correct ;) So that should help you eliminate one immediately, right?

Comment: Yeah, right. I have never thought about dimension analysis. Well, so Is my result correct? Also, I couldn't understand why I got a negative result as a time value. Is there any thing wrong with my solution?

Comment: Remember, the negative sign is not of *time*, it's of a time *interval*. This means that $t_2^\prime - t_1^\prime < 0$, or in other words, in the frame $S^\prime$, the event 2 occurs *before* the event 1.

Comment: Oh, I got it. It's a little mind blowing, I'm not sure It's related to  an animation that I saw in a documentary. There is a stationary observer, and another observer in a train vagon which is moving really fast (I think this is a mind experiment of Einstein, as I remember.) Stationary observer sees two lightning strikes as the same time but one of them is far away from the first one. Einstein as the second observer in the train vagon sees the first lightning strike and then a little while after sees the second lightning strike.

Comment: Which lightning strike does Einstein see first? Closer one to the train or further one? (Sorry for double comment, I reached the limit of characters.)

Comment: The answer to that question is very simple if you remember that everyone sees light travel at $c$, irrespective of their inertial frame. Now, the person in the train wagon is moving *towards* one of the strikes and away from the other. What do you think will happen?

Comment: I think I didn't understand the question. In frame $S$ still lightnings strike at the same time to different positions. But this time the train wagon is travelling from one lightning strike position to other lightning strike's position, right?